# Click event on android buttons (binding only once)

Tags: android, button, binding, xamarin.android, click

I have an Xamarin Android project and need to bind Click events only once. For example, I have this button on an Activity:

```
button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
button.Click += buttonClick;
```

where button is a global variable: `private Button button;`

I have tested checking Click event is null, but It can only appear on left side of a delegate (+=). Some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that? `button.Click` ? The class `android.widget.Button` doesn't have any `Click` class or properties. It should give you a compile-time error.

Comment: Before of this, I got his view: button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);

Comment: And Click is an EventHandler of View

Comment: Well, this means that you are using Xamarin (C#). I assumed it was android native app. You should add xamarin tag.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I'm using Xamarin. Gonna edit. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know a lot of Xamarin, but I think you need to show the `buttonClick` method that you are using

Comment: I may help, but I don't understand what do you mean with "binding only once", can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understand your question, you have a gloval button and you want to subscribe its click event on specific Activity/ Fragment, then you need to define this button like this:

```
public static Button button;
```

A global button should not be defined like `private Button button`.

And you've register its event handler and you possibly want to unsubscribe this click event handler when you leave this activity/ fragment, you can unsubscribe it in your activity's `OnStop` lifecycle like this:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
    button.Click -= buttonClick;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just like this! I think in method OnPause() is also neccesary. Thank you so much!